# how to add Headers when connect to websocket?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

we set up websocket topic with Spring websocket, and then the client side is using Stomp.js to subscribe it; 
it works fine if connect to the websocket service directly; but now we set up Kong as the API Gateway in front of the websocket service; it needs to set header "Host: websocket.com" when connect to it; 
But it doesn't work with Stomp.js;

```
var url='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/websocket/tracker';
var socket = new SockJS(url);
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
var thisheaders={
        Host:'websocket.com'
};
stompClient.connect(thisheaders, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how to add the headers for it? Or the Stomp.js just doesn't support to add headers?

Answer (score 1):

@pankaj malik.. try this

```
var url='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/websocket/tracker';
    var socket = new SockJS(url);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    var thisheaders={
                    login: 'user',
                    passcode: 'AuWcecmbtSz2',
                    AuthToken: getItem('Authentication')//get your authentication token here
                };
    stompClient.connect(thisheaders, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
```

Comment: its not working in case of Kong but issue has been resolved by doing 
var url='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/websocket/tracker?apikey=r783ruhrrhuvrhvrbhjfet3r3r';
Thanks anyway